# posicionar boton alado de input

Tags: asp.net, razor

Como puedo posicionar mi button alado de mi select, ya que aparece abajo

```
  <div class="container body-content">
        <h5><span>Selecciona:</span></h5>
        @Html.DropDownList("datos", items, "", new { @id = "id", @class = "form-control" })
        <button id="Reporte" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Partiendo del supuesto de que estes usando bootstrap, si añades col y row, deberia funcionar `<div class="container body-content"><h5><span>Selecciona:</span></h5><div class="row"><div class="col-6">@Html.DropDownList("datos", items, "", new { @id = "id", @class = "form-control" })</div><div class="col-6"><button id="Reporte" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>  </div></div></div>`